# Android Studio corrupt installation

Tags: android-studio

I must have installed android studio a 100 times and I've never had to many issues. 
I'm using ubuntu 18.04.2 and this is a fresh installation.
I've installed java oracle 8 and was just getting the the android installation part and I can't even install or open android studio. 
After I run ./bin/studio.sh in the terminal I get these two errors:

```
// This is on the interface
Missing essential plugin:

  org.jetbrains.android

Please reinstall Android Studio from scratch.

// this is the error in the terminal
Corrupted Installation: Missing essential plugin:

  org.jetbrains.android

Please reinstall Android Studio from scratch.
```

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio missing essential plugin org.jetbrains.android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61682609/android-studio-missing-essential-plugin-org-jetbrains-android)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it was caused by importing configurations from an earlier version of Android Studio.

I had to do the following to make it launch:
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.1

Comment: If anybody looking to solve for mac scroll down to Habib Kazemi's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61701185/6102488

Comment: Even after deleting ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.1, I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @FernandoSantos Yes. All I had to do was reboot my computer after removing AndroidStudioPreview4.1.

Answer (score 38):

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#4.1-ki-missing-kotlin-plugin

In Android Studio 4.1 Canary 9, you may see the following error when first launching Android Studio after upgrading:

missing essential plugin org.jetbrains.android

This can happen when you import your settings from a previous version of Android Studio. Typically, this means you have a locally installed Kotlin plugin that is not compatible with the new IDE.

To fix this issue, ***remove the Kotlin directory from the following locations***:

`Linux: ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.1`

`Windows: C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview4.1`

`MacOS: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.1`

Because there is no Kotlin plugin compatible with Canary 9 currently available from JetBrains, we have bundled our own Kotlin plugin with the Canary 9 update, so you don't need to manually install a Kotlin plugin.

Comment: This must be accepted answer - more details - more os :)

Answer (score 12):

**for MacOs:**

- **Cmd** + **Space** then type *Terminal*
- run *cd ~/Library/Application Support/Google*
- run *ls*
- run *rm -rf AndroidStudio**

Open *Android Studio* then woala!

Answer (score 7):

For those who are searching for **MacOS** :

Open Terminal from Launchpad, type

```
cd ~/Library/Application Support/Google
```

If the above one didn't work, try this,

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google
```

(Try to use `cd` command and `Tab` key more to check the directories)

Then type,

```
rm -rf AndroidStudio2020.3
```

If it didn't work, change the *AndroidStudio* version according to yours. Again try to use the `Tab` key.

Open *AndroidStudio* app now

Congrats! Keep developing

Answer (score 6):

[image: File Manager listing of files in config folder]

Delete the file named `disabled_plugins.txt`.

Answer (score 4):

I've encountered the same issue by disabling the kotlin plugin (was looking if it would fix another issue) and got the "missing essential plugin" error.

I could start Android studio again by editing the file "disabled_plugins.txt" inside `/Users/MAC_USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1` and removing the kotlin plugin name at the end of file.

Answer (score 4):

after i uninstalled but it didnt solve the problem. The error '...reinstall from scartch' still exist. Then i tried to delete all files* related update at the day. Sort them by data modified to knowing them.

Windows 10 folder:

1. C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2020 (just updated files on that day, or last update files)
2. C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains

Answer (score 3):

There is a file called disabled_plugins.txt which lists which all plugins are disabled for Android studio. You can find this file here

```
/Users/vihaan/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioPreview4.0
```

If by mistake you disable an essential plugin and your ide fails to start you can edit this file and enable the plugin again by removing it from it

Answer (score 3):

For those that come accross this much later, like I did, on Windows, there may be a Local, and a Roaming version of your profile.

You will need delete both:

```
Windows: C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview4.1
```

AND

```
Windows: C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudioPreview4.1
```

I hope that saves someone the frustration in the future!

~BlackXanthus

Answer (score 2):

Removing Android Studio's Config folder saves me.

For Android Studio 4.0 of Mac, path of the folder is:

```
/Users/YOURNAME/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

head over to

```
.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/disabled_plugins.txt
```

in your files directory, if you are in Linux os and delete the last line in the .txt file, where you have disabled the kotlin plugin. Save the file and restart your android studio.

Comment: This worked for ubuntu. thanks. I deleted all previous folders in inside Google folder

Answer (score 1):

[image]

`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions` -
delete this file 100% work

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu try this

1. Go to "/.config/Google/AndroidStudioX"
2. Delete the file named disabled_plugins.txt

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen as well.  For some reason, the install did not include either the 'gradle' or 'plugins' folder in the installation root folder. Luckily, I had an older installation available, and I copied those two folders to the new installation's location. That allowed me to successfully start Android Studio.

Not sure why the install didn't include those folders in the first place.

Comment: Thanks very much. For me I needed to do a fresh installation of linux again anyway so then that fixed the problem. But unfortunately I can't confirm. hopefully someone else who has this problem can up vote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, I had to delete:
`C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\.AndroidStudio4`

I did it after a complete uninstall and reinstall didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when you disable the kotlin plugin in Android Studio

On Mac, access the repository /Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.(your_version)

Then look for the file disabled_plugins.txt normally the last line will be pointed as Kotlin plugin, remove that line.

Restart Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

edit file studio.exe.vmoptions which locate \bin folder , remove line :

-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by deleting the disabled_plugins.txt file from path:

```
C:\Users\{yourUser}\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3
```

Answer (score 0):

For macOS:

Cmd + Space then type Terminal
run cd ~/Library/Application Support/Google
run ls
run rm -rf AndroidStudio*
Open Android Studio then woala!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the plugin from disabled_plugins file
Path : C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2021.3

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcB7I.png)