# Android Studio missing essential plugin org.jetbrains.android

Tags: android-studio, jetbrains-ide

I have just updated to Android Studio 4.1 Canary 9, but I am getting the following error:

```
Missing essential plugin:

  org.jetbrains.android

Please reinstall Android Studio from scratch.
```

[image: Corrupted Installation]

I've tried reinstalling Android Studio from scratch, as the error says, but nothing changes.

Comment: There are several issues now on issuetracker for this incident: 

Some of them are: 

https://issuetracker.google.com/156047819
https://issuetracker.google.com/156048033
https://issuetracker.google.com/156047274
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155985454

Comment: Have the same issue – super annoying!!! They screw up about 10–15% of major/minor updates. I am tired of having to setup everything from scratch after another screw up.

Comment: @Arnyminer Z if you find my answer correct, please mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Incident occurred to me when I click on "disable kotlin" from plugins list section - it was like i pressed an easy to access self-destruct button -_-

Comment: disable Kotlin was the problem here too.

Comment: The same error when disable kotlin in android studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1

Comment: I don't have the `disabled_plugins.txt` file anywhere on my system (MacOS Big Sur)

Comment: How can they release such a thing, you click to disable a plugin and the whole program doesn't load anymore? disable the option to disable critical plugins or give instructions in the error message at least.

Comment: # Just edit/delete this file:
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio<version>\disabled_plugins.txt

# Then restart the PC, if the message appears again.

Comment: This has got to be the new king of Android stupidity. I disabled a few of the plugins I know I don't need (not Kotlin), but instead of warning, Android Studio simply allows you to destroy the entire app with a simple uncheck behavior. So I deleted the disabled_plugins file and now instead of taking over 2 full minutes to open, Android Studio is currently at over 15 minutes and STILL not open, at which time I will have to begin the guessing game from scratch.  Absolutely ABSURD.

Answer (score 388):

**2023/06 Update**

---

### **Windows:**

Just delete this file (or delete the last disabled plugin(s) in this file):

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.AndroidStudio<version>\config\disabled_plugins.txt
```

If you can't find this address try this on Windows:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio<version>\disabled_plugins.txt
```

If you are using **Windows 11**
The App data folder is hidden and needs to be prompted(search [how to take out the missing app data folder in Windows 11](https://www.systweak.com/blogs/how-to-restore-missing-appdata-folder-on-windows/))
Then go to the exact location as earlier mentioned and delete that file

---

### **macOS:**

Delete or modify this file through this address:

```
/Users/%USERNAME%/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio<version>/disabled_plugins.txt
```

---

### **Linux:**

Delete or modify this file through this address:

```
/home/%USERNAME%/.config/share/Google/AndroidStudio<version>/disabled_plugins.txt
```

Comment: the disabled_plugins.txt file may or may not be in this exact location. It could be in AndroidStudio4.0/codestyles or like in my case AndroidStudio4.0/.

Wherever you find it, just delete it and you're good to go.

Comment: This error occured when I disabled Kotlin. So I just removed the Kotlin package line from the file. There's no need to delete the whole file - many people disable plugins for better performance. They'd have to disable all of them again.

Comment: better to just delete the "diable Kotlin" line in that file, if you wanna keep other plugins still disabled

Comment: in my case it was located at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.2

Comment: In my case there was also an Update file I deleted both of them. It is ease to disable unwanted plugins. It is hare to find this problem.

Comment: FWIW, ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio2021.2/disabled_plugins.txt on Ubuntu 20.04.  Obv check the release version embedded in the directory name.

Comment: I don't have the disabled_plugins.txt file in the folder(s) that you refer to. I am on Win 10 and had started a new thread about this issue already about a months ago here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76266649/android-studio-flamingo-2022-2-1-corrupted-unable-to-reinstall/76292143#76292143 but to no avail. None of the Flutter team dev seems to care or read in this forum and I am stuck unable to reinstall Android Studio. Is there anyone here, who can help? This is a serious bug I even posted on the issuetracker but after a months gone by there is still no answer on this. Anyone? Tnx.

Comment: @themightyhulk for your issue, you need to remove your android studio completely and remove the configs as well, then reinstall a fresh version of your android studio

Comment: @AmirHosseinGhasemi Thanks! You're a wizard - no, let me rephrase that..., you are a GOD! What none of the Flutter team was able or bothered to help me with for months on end, your simple - yet genius - advice helped fix in minutes. Thanks so much! I was even able to reimport my saved Flutter tutorial app "Random Name Generator" and got it working again like a charm. Only problem remaining is the Flutter teams constant effup with their fake Kotlin updates & related warnings for the latter within Android studio which has persisted for years now. Let's hope they'll at least do better with that.

Answer (score 110):

On Mac OS

1. Open `~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudioXXXX.X`
2. delete `disabled_plugins.txt`
3. restart Android Studio

Comment: In my case next command in terminal helped to find bad files
`find ~/Library -name disabled_plugins.txt`. I found file
`~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1`

Comment: path is more accurately defined as Users/[your_name]/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio_xxxx

Comment: CHECK location /Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.X 
If the AndroidStudio folder is not present at this location /Users//Library/Preferences/

Comment: In my case, I've disabled several plugins on my own before it stopped working, so I edited the "disabled_plugins.txt" file to only remove the unnecessary lines.

Comment: Thanks @Johann Mainsh Rajpurohit too your comment worked for me

Comment: Note that, if you remove entries from the `disabled_plugins.txt` you might still face the error. Because, some of the dependent modules will be disabled still. IntelliJ shows a warning when you disable it from IntelliJ preference. You lose that benefit when manually editing the file. I delete the file and then manually disable them again from the IntelliJ interface.

Comment: legend thanks
in detail
open terminal and run these commands 
 cd ~/library/application\ support/google
then for listing folders and files 
run ls and find your android studio version after that change directory to 
your android version 

AndroidStudioXXXX.X

Answer (score 88):

For `Windows` users.

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview4.1\disabled_plugins.txt
```

Deleting this file will fix the issue.

More detailed [information](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#4.1-ki-missing-kotlin-plugin).

Comment: Maybe it changed over time, but now this is the correct answer. Also, you could edit it instead.

Comment: Worked for me. In my case it was in C:\Users\<My user name>\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1

Comment: There were other files with the same name in the .android directory. I kept deleting those files which didn't work for me initially. But the file in the directory specified here was the one that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 48):

As the [Known Issues section of the Android Studio 4.1 Preview page](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#4.1-ki-missing-kotlin-plugin) notes, if you are getting this error in Android Studio 4.1 Canary 9, it means that you have a locally installed Kotlin plugin that is not compatible with the new IDE.

To resolve it, you should delete the Kotlin folder from the following locations (from the above linked page), depending on your operating system:

Linux: `~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.1`

Windows: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview4.1`

macOS: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.1`

For Linux and macOS, `~` refers to your home directory, and a directory can be removed from the command line (Terminal) with `rm -rf directory_name_here`.

There is no need to install a replacement Kotlin plugin, as it is bundled in that version of Android Studio.

Comment: For Ubuntu, in my case, `disabled_plugins.txt` was stored in  `~/.config/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1` NOT in `~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1`,

Comment: I've deleted caches and other stuff, but only this solution worked for me

Comment: This is the correct answer period. This seems to be where the settings for android studio 4.1+ are located. NOT in the ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio4.0 folder.

Comment: Works for arctic fox too +1

Comment: Thank you. Removed /Users/vinbrain/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/disabled_plugins 16.58.34.txt works for me.

Answer (score 42):

On **Linux *(Fedora release 30)***, the issue happened after I wanted to disable Kotlin features during installation. I could resolve it by removing configure files:

```
rm -r ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1
```

Or just remove the `disabled_plugins.txt` file:

```
rm  ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/disabled_plugins.txt
```

Sometimes you are compelled to re-extract your android-studio on your Linux machine. Notice that removing `~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/` directory did not help me.

Comment: this worked for me on Ubuntu 20, although you have to reconfig everything from scratch, but that's a small price to pay to get AS running again.

Comment: Worked for me in ubuntu20.04

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But removing the particular entry from the "disabled_plugins.txt" file is a better option.

Answer (score 32):

Disabling the Kotlin plugin for Android Studio 4.x causes this problem and you can't open the Android Studio until enable the Kotlin plugin again. To re-enable plugins without opening Android Studio, you can delete or edit the `disabled_plugins.txt` file from your Android Studio configuration path.

**For Linux distros**, the default configuration directory is `~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.x/`

So deleting `disabled_plugins.txt` will enable all of your disabled plugins and solve your problem.

```
rm ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/disabled_plugins.txt
```

**For macOS**, the default directory is `~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.x`

```
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/disabled_plugins.txt
```

Comment: for Mac? I can't find the file there

Comment: For Mac, it should be `~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.x`

Comment: every time I open it says "The plugin org.jetbrains.kotlin failed to save settings and has been disabled. Please restart Android Studio" and I need to remove or edit this file again. When I try to open the Preferences it doesn't do anything

Comment: Try to remove entire `AndroidStudio4.1` directory.

Comment: Yeah, that worked again but I don't know what happened with some of the plugins I had install. Now everything is broken. Now sure why this happened

Comment: In google directory look for the version of android studio, which you are using +1

Answer (score 14):

**2022 - for MacOs Catalina:**

Finder /
Users /
*your_username /
Library /
Application Support /
Google /
AndroidStudio20021+ /
disable_plugins.txt /

find and delete this line  "org.jetbrains.kotlin"
or
**delete the line causing your problem**

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for me! Does anyone have any idea what caused this? Maybe Google or JetBrains need to fix something on their end. Very annoying.

Answer (score 11):

On Linux, when disabling all plugins, this may happen (Artic Fox). The path is (or may be):

```
~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/disabled_plugins.txt
```

Commenting out entries with a `#` is possible, in order to leave specific plugins disabled.

Comment: Thanks! The path was ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/disabled_plugins.txt

Answer (score 9):

I'm using Linux Ubuntu 18.04 and Android Studio 4.0 and I found disabled_plugins.txt file in this directory:

```
/home/[your_username]/.AndroidStudio4.0/config
```

and after that I found I've put Kotlin plugin at the end of file.
Just remove that line, Android Studio will work.
By the way, on any other OS, you can find your file just by searching **disabled_plugins.txt**.

Comment: hey you know why this error occur "Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.AbstractKotlinGradleModelBuilder'." @AMK

Comment: Sorry for my too late answer but after a little searching, I found two reasons may make so:
1-Android Studio caches
2-Probably bugs in your android studio version
Did you check them? What's the result?

Answer (score 7):

For ***Windows*** users

C:\Users\Admin[if you have username].AndroidStudio4.0\config

There you can find disabled _plugins.txt
delete it and restart android studio

Answer (score 7):

Library -> Application support -> Google -> AndroidStudio4.2 -> disabled_plugins.txt

For MAC Mojave

Answer (score 7):

For **MacOS BigSur**

*Root/Users/{your_user}/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio{version}/disabled_plugins.txt*

Searching for the file won't work.

Gain access to root through *Shift+cmd+g*

Show hidden files using *Shift+cmd+.* (Library will most likely be hidden inside your user folder)

Answer (score 7):

**Got to C:Drive** and delete **disabled_plugins.txt** file

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioVersion\disabled_plugins.txt
```

If you don't find watch this video
https://youtu.be/sMzAw6xaiZU that I made.

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Answer (score 7):

**On Mac OS**

1. in terminal helped to find bad files `find ~/Library -name disabled_plugins.txt`
2. in terminal run `rm '/Users/xxxx/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2021.2/disabled_plugins.txt'`
3. Delete File
4. restart Android Studio

Comment: None of the pathnames I saw above worked for Android Studio Chipmunk on Mac OS X Monterey. The find command was a life-saver!

Comment: Real saviour! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It seems you disabled your plugins before, so find and edit

> disabled_plugins.txt

and delete the plugin you want to enable it.

In windows, the location of file is :

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio...
```

Answer (score 5):

Removing these from `disabled_plugins.txt` fixes the issue if you have disabled some of the plugins. Instead of adding back all the plugins, specify the plugins to enable:

```
groovy, smali, kotlin, junit // (i.e: Enable these)
```

Comment: in my case it was groovy + androidx.compose.plugins.idea

Comment: For me, it was either smali or junit. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1

```
and then delete >>>> disabled_plugin.txt
```

At the place of Dell, you can place your user name or device name(Example - Dell, Lenovo etc).

Comment: That worked for me.

Also you can use this link as it would automatically fill path in windows explorer.
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Android Studio 4.0 from homebrew.
And delete this

```
/Users/[your_name]/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio4.0/disabled_plugin.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

This issue happens because of two reasons.

1. You disabled some plugins from Android Studio and Restarted.
2. Some Plugins disabled by any thread and you starts getting *missing essential plugin org.jetbrains.android* this error message.

Solution is simple.

```
C:\Users\Numan\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1
```

Just go to the latest Android Studio Version, and find the text document file named as **disabled_plugins**. Now open it, and delete the lines which you think has been disabled, or otherwise delete the complete **disabled_plugins** file and open the Android Studio. You can also search **disabled_plugins** in your C Drive, and one text file will appear in case you're unable to locate it from **AppData**.

It Works - Cheers !!!

Answer (score 3):

in macOS Catalina 10.15, this file can be found at
/Users/{your_user_name}/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins

Answer (score 3):

> Delete **disabled_plugins.txt** this contains all disabled plugins

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Error Reason:** This issue occurs after disabling one or more plugin (example: Kotlin) from Android Studio 4.x settings (Android Studio -> Preferences —> Plugins —> Uncheck the Kotlin plugin -> Apply -> Ok —> Restart the Android Studio ==> ERROR prompt

**Solution (Mac Specific)**: Remove the “disabled_plugins.txt” file

1. find ~/Library -name disabled_plugins.txt 
   Ideally, the path would be: /Users//Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio4.x/disabled_plugins.txt
2. rm disabled_plugins.txt
3. Restart the Android Studio

Answer (score 3):

For Android Studio 4.2+ this happens when you disable the Properties Pluggin or Groovy Plugin, you can remove these entries from the disabled_pluggins.txt. For Windows users the file is located at:

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview4.X\disabled_plugins.txt
```

Provide your username in the {username} field in the above address,
alternatively, you could just delete this file as the other answers mention!

Answer (score 3):

All answers related with disabled_plugins.txt is right, but it is enough to just delete the line (it is not necessary to delete this file. Thus, previously disabled plugins will remain disabled.)
[image]

Answer (score 3):

for Android Studio `AndroidStudio2020.3` just remove this file:

```
disabled_plugins.txt
```

from this path:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3
```

Answer (score 2):

only windows user
try this
it works for me
I am Deleting this file  disabled_plugins.txt

C:\Users\ashif.AndroidStudio4.0\config

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to delete `disabled_plugins.txt`.

On **Linux**, **Android Studio 4.1** path is:

```
~/.config/JetBrains/AndroidStudio4.1
```

Comment: Yes, and this solution works also for Android Studio 2021.3 (Dolphin).

Answer (score 2):

In mac os use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to show hidden files and when find disabled_plugins.txt

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JetBrains Tool Box to install just find the disabled_plugins.txt file on the path below: C:\Users[YOUR USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2021.1

Answer (score 2):

the same issue happened for me when i disbaled the Groovy, Kotlen, C and C++ using Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 in windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 64bis, and i have solved the problem by closing Android Studio then deleting the file below:

C:\Users[your user name]\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2021.3\disabled_plugins.txt

then reopening Android Studio, also i did Repair IDE from File menu

Answer (score 1):

On **Linux** with **Android Studio 4.1**

it was another path for me, maybe this is the new format now?

> ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

Comment: that seems to be the location on Ubuntu 20. this seems to be the better [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64384209/2445763)

Comment: @lasec0203 nope I'm not using Ubuntu 20 rather 18.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue due to disabling *Kotlin* plugin.

Fix was as simple as removing the *Kotlin* line from `~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/disabled_plugins.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following directory:

- Search for **%appdata%** in the windows search bar
- **Google\AndroidStudio4.1**
- delete **disabled_plugins.txt**

Answer (score 1):

Ok, none of the above worked for me, and I was actually going quite insane... Until I finally found THIS video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MbXG8qwmMA

and realized that I'd been deleting in the WRONG .AndroidStudio directory!!  There is a .AndroidStudio4.0 folder in the path described in other answers here, and I just didn't look carefully enough at the name... Because of course, my Android Studio version is 4.1, not 4.0!  And they've moved those files to a different location, which is probably why this problem arises in the first place...

So my correct location of the error-causing file is now:

> C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\disabled_plugins.txt

Try it, or otherwise just look for a folder with the correct version name in it, or just search your entire user directory for the file name! My Android Studio works again now!

Answer (score 1):

**I had the same issue due to disabling the kotlin plugin.**

**Solution:**

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Google

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google

Delete the entire google folder at these two locations then it will work and This solution works for me.

Answer (score 1):

For MAC Monterrey:

`rm -rf /Users/[*your_user*]/LibraryApplication\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio2021.3/disabled_plugins.txt`

Comment: It works for me, but I had another folder name (`AndroidStudio2022.2`). Probably, when you read this comment you might also have a newer version of Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

**Android Studio 4.1.1**

I have disabled some plugins (trying to speed up Android Studio) and got this error message above.

So I opend a file explorer, enable hidden files and navigate to:

> C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1

and deleted the txt file `disabled_plugins`

Now Android studio works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by deleting the files in the following folder:
...\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview2020.3\plugins
probably a problem on some plugin, kotlin in my case
Restart android Studio (ArtFox canary version)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it happened because I disabled JUnit. You should not disable basic android studio plugins.

so remove those plugins from disabled_plugins.txt under the following directory for windows

```
C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio_your_version\disabled_plugins.txt
```

and removed basic android plugins names from there.

For me, it was under

```
C:\Users\mirza\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.2
```

If you are not sure how many and which plugin you should remove then do a trial and error method, which mean removing one plugin from the file and starting an android studio. Do this until the studio starts without andy error

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution helpful after upgrade to Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Canary 2 from Jetbrains Toolbox.

> Navigate to user -> make Library package visible(it's hidden in most
> cases) -> Application support -> Google -> delete the old directories
> of android studio

Comment: Your `stackoverflow question` link above leads nowhere, do you have an update ?

Answer (score -1):

This seems to happen when you try to install the provided plugin when upgrading to AS2020.3.1.5. But I can't find the suggested disabled_plugin.xml in the folder `C:\Users\[your_name]\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudioPreview2020.3`.

Anyhow, I am still able to open the previous 2020.3.1.x version, so it may be stored somewhere else... (since theese two versions are using the same Library/Application Support/ path).

Answer (score -1):

It seems there are many sources of this problem. I had the issue with Android Studio 2020.3.1 Canary 5.  All was fine using 2020.3.1 Canary 4, despite both using the same configuration files.

In my case the offender was the Kotlin folder located at:

C:\Users<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview2020.3\plugins

I note an earlier answer has the Kotlin folder at the level where in my case the 'plugins' folder was located. I moved the folder out, started and finally Canary 5 started.

Starting Canary 4 again recreated the folder and reported 'corrupt installation', and made the problem return.  But removing the folder again allowed Canary 5 to run again.