# How to modify dependencies of `:app:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]` and similar tasks in Android's build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, conan

I'm trying to integrate the conan package manager to install C++ dependencies for my Android app. I first followed [the official Conan tutorial](https://docs.conan.io/2/examples/cross_build/android/android_studio.html#examples-cross-build-android-studio) and it works. However, the task from the official example always runs and is never up-to-date. This is problematic as every time this task runs, it regenerates the cmake dependency files, making cmake rerun and all code needs to be recompiled. This significantly increases the edit-build-debug cycle.

Therefore, I'm trying to make a more complex gradle task that will know when the conan installation is up-to-date and thus avoid re-running cmake every time I run the app.

This is what I came up with:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/69099942/213057
tasks.register("prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel"){}

abstract class ConanInstallTask extends DefaultTask {
    @Internal
    String buildType;

    @Internal
    String abi;

    @TaskAction
    void conanInstall() {
        def buildDir = new File("app")
        buildDir.mkdirs()
        def cmd = ['conan', 'install', '/path/to/conanfile/folder/', '-of', '.',
                    "--profile:host", "android-ndk-r25c-" + abi,
                    "--profile:build", "macos-xcode-universal-clang-14.0.3",
                   "--settings", "build_type=" + buildType,
                   "--build", "missing",
                   "-c", "tools.cmake.cmake_layout:build_folder_vars=['settings.arch']",
                   "-c", "tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:generator=Ninja"]
        print(">> ${cmd} \n")

        def sout = new StringBuilder(), serr = new StringBuilder()
        def proc = cmd.execute(null, buildDir)
        proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
        proc.waitFor()
        println "$sout $serr"
        if (proc.exitValue() != 0) {
            throw new Exception("out> $sout err> $serr" + "\nCommand: ${cmd}")
        }
    }
}

android {
    // the usual cmake-based android NDK project
}

dependencies {
    // also as usual
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def buildType = variant.buildType.name
    android.defaultConfig.externalNativeBuild.cmake.abiFilters.each { abi ->
        def conanInstallTask = project.tasks.create( "conanInstall${abi.capitalize()}${buildType.capitalize()}", ConanInstallTask)
        conanInstallTask.buildType = buildType.capitalize()
        conanInstallTask.abi = abi
        conanInstallTask.inputs.file '/path/to/conanfile/folder/conanfile.py'
        // note: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/unexpected-up-to-date-task-while-output-file-is-missing/5216/2
        conanInstallTask.outputs.upToDateWhen {
            def arch = {
                switch( abi ) {
                    case 'arm64-v8a': return 'armv8'
                    case 'armeabi-v7a': return 'armv7'
                    default: return abi
                }
            }()
            file( "build/${arch}/${buildType.capitalize()}/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake" ).exists()
        }

        // how to make configureCMake${buildType}[${abi}] depend on conanInstallTask?
        variant.externalNativeBuildProviders[0].get().dependsOn conanInstallTask
        // needed for Android Studio code model to be aware of conan
        project.tasks.findByName('prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel').dependsOn( conanInstallTask )
    }
}
```

The snippet above works correctly until I click `clean` in Android Studio. The next build then fails because `configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]`, and similar, fail because they can't find files that conan install task should produce. The conan install tasks are executed, but in parallel or after `configureCMake...` tasks.

How to make `configureCMake...` tasks depend on my newly added task using Android Gradle Plugin v8's API?

As you can see from the snippet above, `variant.externalNativeBuildProviders[0].get()` does not refer to the cmake configure task - it refers to the actual code build task, which happens "too late".

I've also tried finding tasks by name, but this doesn't work (see below):

```
// doesn't work - NullPointerException on gradle sync
project.tasks.findByName(":app:configureCMake${buildType.capitalize()}[${abi}]").dependsOn( conanInstallTask ) 

// also doesn't work, gradle sync passes, but throws NPE on app run (app build, however, does work)
project.tasks.findByName("configureCMake${buildType.capitalize()}[${abi}]").dependsOn( conanInstallTask )

// also doesn't work, gradle sync passes, but throws NPE on app run (app build, however, does work)
project.tasks.findByPath(":app:configureCMake${buildType.capitalize()}[${abi}]").dependsOn( conanInstallTask)
```

EDIT:

for some weird reason, this appears to be working correctly, although I don't have any explanation why:

```
def cmakeConfigureTask = project.tasks.findByPath(":app:configureCMake${buildType.capitalize()}[${abi}]") 
// or def cmakeConfigureTask = project.tasks.findByName("configureCMake${buildType.capitalize()}[${abi}]")
if ( cmakeConfigureTask != null ) {
    cmakeConfigureTask.dependsOn(conanInstallTask)
}
```

It appears that `:app:configureCMake...` sometimes exists, and sometimes doesn't ‍♂️

Comment: Hi! Did you resolve the issue somehow? I am facing similar problem... but using Kotlin instead of Java (that for me is another challenge). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: No, I didn't. But, as you can see from my edit of the original question, I've found a workaround that always works correctly, although I can't explain why.

Comment: I am working on a similar topic. I was thinking to create a new gradle plugin to always work with conan... something you can use as:
conan {
  api_level = 29
}