# Android Studio 4.1 Start Failed in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: android, android-studio-4.1

The Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio (id=com.google.gct, path=/opt/AndroidStudioLatest/android-studio/plugins/google-cloud-tools-as) plugin depends on plugin "org.jetbrains.android" that failed to load
2020-11-09 23:09:41,536 [   3213]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Missing essential plugins: org.jetbrains.android
com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore$EssentialPluginMissingException: Missing essential plugins: org.jetbrains.android
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.checkEssentialPluginsAreAvailable(PluginManagerCore.java:1638)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializePlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1695)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.loadAndInitializePlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1917)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.lambda$initPlugins$6(PluginManagerCore.java:1319)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:616)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApplyStage(CompletableFuture.java:628)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenApply(CompletableFuture.java:1996)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initPlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1318)
at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.initApplication(ApplicationLoader.kt:375)
at com.a.c.c.d.aw.a(aw.java:65)
at com.a.c.c.d.aY.a(aY.java:98)
at com.a.c.c.d.a1.b(a1.java:260)
at com.a.c.c.d.a1.a(a1.java:122)
at com.a.c.c.d.aC.a(aC.java:56)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:19)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:303)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:245)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:47)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-11-09 23:09:41,540 [   3217]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 4.1  Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069
2020-11-09 23:09:41,540 [   3217]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_242-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o
2020-11-09 23:09:41,540 [   3217]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux

Corrupted Installation: Missing essential plugin:

org.jetbrains.android

Please reinstall Android Studio from scratch.

Comment: How are you launching it?

Comment: I install it in opt folder By Terminal using this command  -----> 1.cd /opt  2. cd AndroidStudioLatest                                                                                                      3. cd android-studio                                                                                                          4. cd bin                                                                                                                               5. ./studio.sh

Comment: Please help me out. Is it Android Studio plugin error ?

Comment: Try one of these: In terminal, check your java version by writing `java -version` and you should have your java version displayed. Ideally, it needs to be `1.8.0`. If it's present, good. If not - google on how to install java on linux. Then try unpacking your Android Studio in your `Downloads` folder and try running it from there, instead of `/opt` folder since you won't need `sudo` privileges for running from `Downloads`

Comment: I follow your instruction @Rey but the problem still not fixed. Please help me out.

Comment: Here, try following what people suggest in this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61682609/android-studio-missing-essential-plugin-org-jetbrains-android

Comment: Thanks, @Rey I follow this above link now it works. Thanks a lot my friend.