# Not able to use Android Studio after uninstall Kotlin plugin

Tags: android-studio

I uninstalled kotlin plugin and at this moment my Android Studio crashed.
People in the internet said i should delete deleted_plugins.txt and it'll work again but unfortunatly it doesnt worked anymore.
I uninstalled whole android studio multiple times and evene followed a couple instructions how to completely delete Android Studio from my PC but still, when im going to install it again the same error:

```
Missing essential plugin:

  org.jetbrains.android

Please reinstall Android Studio from scratch.
```

Shows up again and again. I also tried to go to Visual Studio Code, but i need Android Studio for the emulator to work so i have no choice then fixing this.
I cant do anything at all so please help me I appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio missing essential plugin org.jetbrains.android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61682609/android-studio-missing-essential-plugin-org-jetbrains-android)

Comment: No, i tried this before i deleted all Android Studio folders at it did not work for me..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at JetBrains' [Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/). You won't need to worry about manually installing/uninstalling IDEs (developed by JetBrains) anymore!

Comment: I installed it and it also updated my android studio, but when its starting the problem is still the same

Comment: Have you opened Android Studio from Toolbox app or just updated? The reason why I suggested to install Toolbox is that it handles its apps separately from what you would install manually. 

The install paths are different: 
Windows: %LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps
macOS: ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps
Linux: ~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps

Comment: I opened it from Toolbox App.. I have no clue what is wrong with my pc,i also installed and downlaoded it again via toolbox App

Comment: I also recognized that i dont have the folders in my .android AndroidStudio4.1 .m2 .... in my C://Users/Username folder

Comment: Seems like this problem occurred in 4.1 Canary 9 also (https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/05/android-studio-41-canary-9-available.html). I couldn't find the workaround though.

Comment: You could also try the folders suggested here:  https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008211119-Android-Studio-4-1-Canary-9-Corrupted-Installation-?page=1#community_comment_360002378039

Comment: Hello, i visited the Link and there were a download option for AndroidStudio 4.2. I downloaded it. I have the whole Folder on my desktop now and not in my C: drive but i could start the IDE and it works fine now. I'll write my app tomorrow and let you know if its working perfect. For now, thank you, you helped me alot, i can finally code again =')

Comment: Glad that it works for now. I'd suggest to use Toolbox in the future though (after a clean install of course) and you won't have to deal with such issues anymore.

Comment: I use jetbrains toolbox and get "Missing essential plugin: org.jetbrains.android" at startup.

Comment: @Denis not sure, but doing what's suggested here https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#studio-config-directories could reset all your current (most probably faulty) configurations and therefore get back to the default state where you don't get this error.