# NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/plugins/gradle/tooling/ModelBuilderService

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

How can I fix this error? It appears when I run the project in Intellij IDEA with GRADLE 6.7 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I need was just to upgrade IntelliJ IDEA to the latest version. I checked for an update manually﻿:

- In the Settings/Preferences dialog Ctrl+Alt+S, select Appearance,
  and Behavior | System Settings | Updates.
- Click the Check Now button to see if a newer version is available.

Answer (score 14):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-866) caused by the incompatible Kotlin plug-in update. The issue is already fixed. The solution is to either update Kotlin plug-in again to get the version compatible with IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 release or update IntelliJ IDEA to 2020.3.1 version.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I just needed to disable kotlin.
if you dont need kotlin at the moment you can disbale it in idea.
just got to Plugins>Installed->Kotlin then disable for all projects.

Comment: This could generate another issue, I had to reinstall Android Studio :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61682609/android-studio-missing-essential-plugin-org-jetbrains-android