# Android Studio on startup: "Missing essential plugin: org.jetbrains.android. Please reinstall Android Studio from scratch."

Tags: android-studio

I can't open `Android Studio 2020.3.1 Arctic Fox`. On `Kubuntu 20.04.` An error pops up:

```
"Missing essential plugin:

  org.jetbrains.android

Please reinstall Android Studio from scratch."
```

[image]

So far I have tried:

- reinstallation + restart
- `Linux: ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.2`
- `rm -rf AndroidStudio4.2`
- `rm -rf AndroidStudio2020.3`
- I tried to delete the file disabled_plugins.txt but for me, it does not occur.

[image]

[I use toolbox-app.](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/)

UPDATE:

I installed a newer version (Android Studio 2021.1.1 Canary 6) and everything is working fine.

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio missing essential plugin org.jetbrains.android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61682609/android-studio-missing-essential-plugin-org-jetbrains-android)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I faced this issue on AndroidStudio2020.3 version on Mac OS and I resolved it by doing these below steps:

- Go to /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3
- Give the "ls -l" command to see the list of files and check if the "disabled_plugins.txt" file is present
- if present delete the file by running "rm -Rf disabled_update.txt" command and this should fix the Missing essential plugin error for android studio.
- Launch android studio and it should be running smoothly now.

Comment: Tried the exact same steps and didn't work.

Comment: clearing all file contents will also work.

Comment: Renamed `disabled_plugins.txt` and the error message is no more.   Catalina, Arctic Fox 2020 3.1 Patch 4.  Would be nice to know the what & why of the issue, though happy that it is resolved.

Comment: To me it worked, but instead of delete disabled_update I deleted disabled_plugins

Comment: The path has changed. The new path is : /Users/USER_NAME/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudioVERSION/

Answer (score 3):

- Go to ./.config/Google with  `cd ./.config/Google`.
- Remove AndroidStudio2020.3 with the command :
  `rm -r AndroidStudio2020.3`.
- Run ./studio.sh and now it should work correctly

Answer (score 2):

On Macbook.

Followed the steps of ChandraGudimetla. Deleting the file did not work.

So I deleted the whole AndroidStudio directory. That worked.

i.e. Go to /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3. [or whatever version is there]

From Majda post...for my version of AndroidStudio:

`rm -r AndroidStudio2020.1`

I had two versions Bumble and AndroidStudio4.1. Deleted both directories.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am a linux user too, Ubuntu user.
Is their **Ubuntu Software** or any other **Software Store** in Kubuntu? If yes, try installing Android Studio from there.

Comment: Unfortunately the same issue, but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, the same cleanup is needed, the directory to remove is a bit different
C:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio(whateverversion)
or
%AppData%\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio(whateverversion)