# How to install AndroidStudio with plugins?

Tags: android-studio

When I start my AndroidStudio the following message occurs:

[image]

After reinstalling it, the same thing comes up. I don't know what to do at all.

Any recommendatinos?

Answer (score 1):

Other same question, post in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61682609/android-studio-missing-essential-plugin-org-jetbrains-android)

If you can find **disabled_plugins.txt**, just delete it.

For Windows

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio<version>\disabled_plugins.txt
```