# Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1 corrupted - unable to reinstall

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently did an update for Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1 which the program prompted me to do as the Kotlin package seemed to have an update issue.

However, after having done so, the update progress didn't succeed in updating the Kotlin issue. After a bit of searching, I found the packages and installed them manually as being referred to by an stackoverflow post.

The result is a corrupted program and although I have tried to reinstall multiple times, I am stuck with the following result.

[image]

Does anyone know, how to get this fixed? I have tried various things after scouring posts from users on stackoverflow who are having similar issues but to no avail.

The program seems completely buggered. Please note, that I have not tried to uninstall settings etc as of yet since I got a trial app in a folder somewhere and am afraid to lose it.

Looking forward to any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check here pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61682609/android-studio-missing-essential-plugin-org-jetbrains-android

Comment: @Zain Thanks for your reply. However, I already tried that (forgot to mention this in my initial post - apologies). My current Android Studio folder using the path in the post you linked to is showing the following folders https://ibb.co/XzJpHGt and accessing the last folder AndroidStudio2022.2 the content looks like this https://ibb.co/RQNSR9p which is a problem, since the disabled_plugins.txt file is nowhere to be found. That goes for all the five Android Studio versions in the first image. So I can't delete that file since it doesn't exist. Any thoughts or ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Anyone able to shed some light on the above and my latest response/comment under it? Thanks in advance. PS: @Machavity I know, my last answer didn't solve my own problem and that you deleted it due to guidelines, but I posted it as an answer as to "bump" the thread and keep it alive in order to make people see my comments (ie. in response to Zain's suggestion). I doubt, that this will happen when only posting a comment. So, I'd like to ask you to kindly refrain from deleting as there is no other way of renewing this thread's activity. Thanks.

Comment: I started an issue on Google's issuetracker on this matter, but after an initial response, which didn't produce any results, there seems to be nobody really taking this problem serious at Google, although the application doesn't install, no matter what one tries. Is there anybody from the company checking up on this in the forums???