# Here was an error happen on my MacBook Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I use my MacBook M1 Chip to open the Android Studio 2023.1 and find out the "Start Failed" error, and it was the Internal Error

I found these error codes on screen:

```
com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore$EssentialPluginMissingException: Missing essential plugins: com.android.tools.design, org.jetbrains.android
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.checkEssentialPluginsAreAvailable(PluginManagerCore.java:761)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializePlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:854)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializeAndSetPlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1068)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader$scheduleLoading$pluginSetDeferred$1.invokeSuspend(PluginDescriptorLoader.kt:397)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
```

Please someone help me out how to solve it.

I reinstall both Intellij IDEA and Android Studio and hope that was fixed. But it wasn't

Comment: This may be helpful (Deleting a text file): [Android Studio missing essential plugin org.jetbrains.android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61913060/1270000)